# Automate to run multiple servers prior starting springboot eclipse/Intellij

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a springboot application that depends on Messaging Service that needs to be started manually prior to starting the Springboot server, we need this only for development purposes using eclipe/intellij, is there any way to automate to run the dependent MQ server before starting spring boot server?

Comment: Docker compose is your friend

Comment: Unfortunately, docker is not an option, any script-based or IDE options are possible given development enveronment

Comment: I would highly recommend to change the development environment instead of making your own life miserable. It can never be worse than installing/configuring/running stuff locally and not within a container.